# How to move from one fragment to another fragment?

Tags: java, android, fragment

I have a `Tablayout` in main and 
I want move from a fragment to `tablayout` to new fragment

My code :

```
            public void onClick(View v) {

            Fragment fragment = new Main2Activity();

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(container.getId(), fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();


        }
```

And New Fragment :

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main2, viewGroup, false);
    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return view;
}
```

But when I clicked on `TextView` the Toast is showed but `activity_main2` is not show

The first fragment

[image]

The second fragment

[image]

Comment: What do you mean is when you click the `TextView` from FragmentA, and it display the FragmentB or it will display the NewActivity?

Answer (score 0):

Communication among fragment can only possible through interface and implementing that interface into parent activity.
you can take the help from https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating